# C++ vector as a member variable

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to use a vector as a member variable.

```
GameOfLife.h
class GameOfLifeManager {
    std::vector<Cell::Cell> cells;
    ...

GameOfLife.cpp

...
cells.push_back(Cell::Cell(x,y,false));
...
```

and Cells.h looks like this

```
#ifndef CELL_H_
#define CELL_H_

namespace Cell {

class Cell {

    bool alive;

    int posX;
    int posY;

    Cell* left;
    Cell* right;
    Cell* top;
    Cell* bottom;

    Cell* topLeft;
    Cell* topRight;
    Cell* bottomRight;
    Cell* bottomLeft;

public:

    Cell(int x, int y, bool alive);

    int CountNeighbours();
    void Kill();
    void Resurrect();

};


} /* namespace Zell */
#endif /* CELL_H_ */
```

if I try to call `cells.push_back(Cell::Cell(x,y,false))` eclipse tells me "required from here"
I also can't decrypt the error msg. Any ideas what went wrong?

---

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type ‘::fwprintf’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 149, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::fwscanf’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 150, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::getwc’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 151, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::getwchar’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 152, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::fgetws’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 145, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::fputwc’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 146, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::fputws’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 147, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::fwide’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 148, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::mbstate_t’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 66, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar C/C++ Problem ‘::wint_t’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 141, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::btowc’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 143, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::fgetwc’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 144, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘void GameOfLifeManager::operator delete [](void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace    GameOfLife      line 100, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem ‘void* GameOfLifeManager::operator new(GameOfLifeManager::std::size_t, const GameOfLifeManager::std::nothrow_t&)’ may not be declared within a namespace  GameOfLife      line 102, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem ‘void* GameOfLifeManager::operator new [](GameOfLifeManager::std::size_t, const GameOfLifeManager::std::nothrow_t&)’ may not be declared within a namespace   GameOfLife      line 104, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem ‘void GameOfLifeManager::operator delete(void*, const GameOfLifeManager::std::nothrow_t&)’ may not be declared within a namespace GameOfLife      line 106, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem ‘void GameOfLifeManager::operator delete [](void*, const GameOfLifeManager::std::nothrow_t&)’ may not be declared within a namespace  GameOfLife      line 108, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem ‘void* GameOfLifeManager::operator new(GameOfLifeManager::std::size_t, void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace GameOfLife      line 111, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem ‘void* GameOfLifeManager::operator new [](GameOfLifeManager::std::size_t, void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace  GameOfLife      line 113, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem   required from here  GameOfLifeManager.cpp   /GameOfLife/src line 27 C/C++ Problem ‘void GameOfLifeManager::operator delete(void*, void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace    GameOfLife      line 117, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem ‘::wcstoull’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 260, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::__gnu_cxx’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 266, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::__gnu_cxx’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 267, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::__gnu_cxx’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 268, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘mbstate_t’ in namespace ‘GameOfLifeManager::std’ does not name a type    GameOfLife      line 65, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/char_traits.h C/C++ Problem ‘void* GameOfLifeManager::operator new(GameOfLifeManager::std::size_t)’ may not be declared within a namespace    GameOfLife      line 94, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new    C/C++ Problem ‘void* GameOfLifeManager::operator new [](GameOfLifeManager::std::size_t)’ may not be declared within a namespace GameOfLife      line 96, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new    C/C++ Problem ‘void GameOfLifeManager::operator delete(void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace   GameOfLife      line 98, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcschr’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 206, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wscanf’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 205, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsrchr’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 208, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcspbrk’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 207, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wmemchr’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 210, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsstr’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 209, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcstoll’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 259, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcstold’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 250, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsxfrm’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 198, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcstoul’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 197, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wmemcmp’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 200, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wctob’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 199, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wmemmove’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 202, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wmemcpy’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 201, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wprintf’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 204, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wmemset’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 203, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsrtombs’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 189, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsspn’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 190, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsncmp’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 187, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsncpy’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 188, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcstok’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 195, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcstol’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 196, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcstod’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 191, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcstof’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 193, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcscoll’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 181, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcscpy’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 182, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcscat’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 179, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcscmp’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 180, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcslen’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 185, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsncat’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 186, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcscspn’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 183, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcsftime’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 184, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::vswprintf’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 169, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::vfwscanf’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 166, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::vfwprintf’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 164, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::ungetwc’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 163, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::wcrtomb’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 178, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::vwscanf’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 176, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::vwprintf’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 174, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::vswscanf’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 172, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::mbsrtowcs’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 156, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::mbsinit’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 155, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::mbrtowc’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 154, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::mbrlen’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 153, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::swscanf’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 162, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::swprintf’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 160, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::putwchar’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 158, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘::putwc’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 157, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwchar    C/C++ Problem ‘void GameOfLifeManager::operator delete [](void*, void*)’ may not be declared within a namespace GameOfLife      line 118, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/new   C/C++ Problem ‘::lconv’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 55, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/clocale    C/C++ Problem ‘::setlocale’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 56, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/clocale    C/C++ Problem ‘::localeconv’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 57, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/clocale    C/C++ Problem ‘::isalnum’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 66, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::isalpha’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 67, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::iscntrl’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 68, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::isdigit’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 69, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::isgraph’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 70, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::islower’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 71, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::isprint’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 72, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::ispunct’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 73, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::isspace’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 74, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::isupper’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 75, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::isxdigit’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 76, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::tolower’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 77, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::wctrans_t’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 84, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::toupper’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 78, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cctype C/C++ Problem ‘::wint_t’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 86, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::wctype_t’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 85, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswalpha’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 89, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswalnum’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 88, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswcntrl’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 93, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswblank’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 91, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswdigit’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 95, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswctype’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 94, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswlower’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 97, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswgraph’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 96, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswpunct’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 99, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswprint’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 98, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype    C/C++ Problem ‘::iswupper’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 101, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype   C/C++ Problem ‘::iswspace’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 100, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype   C/C++ Problem ‘::towlower’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 104, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype   C/C++ Problem ‘::towupper’ has not been declared    GameOfLife      line 105, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype   C/C++ Problem ‘::iswxdigit’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 102, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype   C/C++ Problem ‘::towctrans’ has not been declared   GameOfLife      line 103, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype   C/C++ Problem ‘::wctrans’ has not been declared GameOfLife      line 106, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype   C/C++ Problem ‘::wctype’ has not been declared  GameOfLife      line 107, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/cwctype   C/C++ Problem no matching function for call to ‘operator new(sizetype, void*)’  GameOfLife      line 120, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/new_allocator.h   C/C++ Problem   required from ‘static void GameOfLifeManager::__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::construct(_Alloc&, GameOfLifeManager::__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::pointer, const
_Tp&) [with _Tp = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell; _Alloc = GameOfLifeManager::std::allocator<GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell>; GameOfLifeManager::__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::pointer = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*]’    GameOfLife      line 202, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/ext/alloc_traits.h    C/C++ Problem   required from ‘void GameOfLifeManager::std::vector<_Tp,
_Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell; _Alloc = GameOfLifeManager::std::allocator<GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell>; GameOfLifeManager::std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell]’   GameOfLife      line 885, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h C/C++ Problem   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator GameOfLifeManager::std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*; _ForwardIterator = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’    GameOfLife      line 77, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h   C/C++ Problem   required from ‘void GameOfLifeManager::std::vector<_Tp,
_Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(GameOfLifeManager::std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell; _Alloc = GameOfLifeManager::std::allocator<GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell>; GameOfLifeManager::std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = GameOfLifeManager::__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*, GameOfLifeManager::std::vector<GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell> >; typename GameOfLifeManager::std::_Vector_base<_Tp, _Alloc>::pointer = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*]’ GameOfLife      line 360, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/vector.tcc   C/C++ Problem   required from ‘_ForwardIterator GameOfLifeManager::std::__uninitialized_move_if_noexcept_a(_InputIterator,
_InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, _Allocator&) [with _InputIterator = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*; _ForwardIterator = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*; _Allocator = GameOfLifeManager::std::allocator<GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell>]’    GameOfLife      line 283, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h  C/C++ Problem   required from ‘_ForwardIterator GameOfLifeManager::std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator,
_InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, GameOfLifeManager::std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*; _ForwardIterator = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*; _Tp = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell]’  GameOfLife      line 260, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h  C/C++ Problem  required from ‘_ForwardIterator GameOfLifeManager::std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator,
_InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*; _ForwardIterator = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell*]’    GameOfLife      line 119, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h  C/C++ Problem no matching function for call to ‘operator new(sizetype, void*)’  GameOfLife      line 85, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_construct.h   C/C++ Problem   required from ‘void GameOfLifeManager::std::vector<_Tp,
_Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell; _Alloc = GameOfLifeManager::std::allocator<GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell>; GameOfLifeManager::std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = GameOfLifeManager::Cell::Cell]’   GameOfLife      line 893, external location: /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_vector.h C/C++ Problem make:
*** [src/GameOfLifeManager.o] Error 1   GameOfLife          C/C++ Problem
```

Comment: Do you have C++11 support? Otherwise your `GameOfLifeManager` class declaration is wrong.

Comment: It's a bit pointless as well, considering it will be default-constructed anyway.

Comment: So you know, you don't have to say `std::vector<Cell::Cell> cells = {};` -- all that does is create an empty vector, which the constructor will do anyway.  (Add to that, i'm about 74% sure that C++ doesn't let you initialize objects at the point of declaration like that, unless C++11 has changed significantly in that regard.)

Comment: @juanchopanza : yes I am using -std=c++11 with gcc 4.7.2. But I am wondering why would the class declaration be wrong?

Comment: @cHao: It has, actually.

Comment: Before C++11 you couldn't initialize non-static data members at the point of declaration.

Comment: @MaikKlein: Please format your error message, it looks like a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have `#include` statements inside a namespace.

Not in the code you're showing... probably in your source file.